# How to make initWithCoder() become failable when unarchiving an invalid file?

Tags: swift

Let assume that I created a file from `NSKeyedArchiver`, and the file was modified / replaced by third parties. So when I try to unarchive the file. It should be fail to initialize the object.

But initWithCoder() is not a failable initialzer. So I cannot return nil when the data is invalid. But at the same time. `NSKeyedUnarchiver` can return nil value when unarchiving object. So I'm really confuse that how to return a nil object in initWithCoder().

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `nil` from `awakeAfterUsingCoder(_:)`

From [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder:):

> You must return self from `initWithCoder:`. If you have an advanced need that requires substituting a different object after decoding, you can do so in `awakeAfterUsingCoder:`.

```
class Foo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    override init() {}
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    }
    override func awakeAfterUsingCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) -> AnyObject? {
        return nil
    }
}

let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(Foo())
let obj: AnyObject? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) // -> nil
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be the only solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may have changed in Swift 2.0. Looking at the API, the init is nullable:

```
@protocol NSCoding

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder; // NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER

@end
```

Xcode Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o)

Comment: This is true - you can now return `nil` from `init?(coder:)` in Swift. But Xcode still complains if you try to return `nil` from `initWithCoder:` in Objective-C.